# Uncaught ReferenceError when executing on different computer

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below script works fine on one of my computers but when executing it on another I get `uncaught referenceerror $ is not defined`. It is the same error on another similar page. Also it says unable to load resource of the ajax.google... source.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //add dynamic fields to add more addresses
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
            var $address = $('#address');
            var num = $('.clonedAddress').length;
            var newNum = new Number(num + 1);
            var newElem = $address.clone().attr('id', 'address' + 
newNum).addClass('clonedAddress');

            //set all div id's and the input id's
            newElem.children('div').each (function (i) {
                this.id = 'input' + (newNum*11 + i);
            });
            newElem.find('input').each (function () {
                this.id = this.id + newNum;
                this.name = this.name + newNum;
            });

            if (num > 0) {
                $('.clonedAddress:last').after(newElem);
            } else {
                $address.after(newElem);
            }


            $('#btnDel').removeAttr('disabled');

            if (newNum == 2) $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');//number of 
field sets that can be added
        });
        $('#btnDel').click(function() {
            $('.clonedAddress:last').remove();
            $('#btnAdd').removeAttr('disabled');
            if ($('.clonedAddress').length == 0) {
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you are loading jQuery from online. `no internet = no jQuery`

Answer (score 1):

the second error will cause the first.  Unable to load `jQuery` will cause `$` to be undefined.  And since you're loading it from a CDN, one of two things is possible, either a) your network is down, or b) google's CDN is down or no longer hosting through that path.  Since you say it works on another computer, my inclination is that a) your network is down.

As Rocket explained in the comments, it may not be that your network is completely down, but simply that you cannot get to the google CDN.  Firewall, or something else, may be causing this issue.

---

If you might have computers where the network is down, its advisable to download the compressed jQuery source, and localize that file.  If you're going to do this, I highly recommend using something higher than 1.3 if at all possible.

Comment: Or some sort of firewall is blocking Google's CDN (or blocking JavaScript in general), or something.

Comment: Thanks @Rocket, that's a good point.  I've updated my answer to reflect that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

@Kirean's answer is right, but I wanted to share what HTML5-Boilerplate uses to cover this scenario (too much for a comment)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/path/to/local/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

It attempts to load jQuery from Google's CDN, and if unsuccessful (`window.jQuery` is undefined), it loads your local version instead as a fallback.